# stacktrace of few threads show nothing except __nanosleep_nocancel from core generated

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

stack trace of the thread show nothing except __nanosleep_nocancel from the core dump'ed using gdb on Debian. This is been observed when analyzing the threads stack trace from the coredump generated by the kernel which is triggered from the application when anomaly found

```
Thread 5 (Thread 0x7f8b307bf700 (LWP 27000)): 
#0 ......Application function ..... 
#1......Application function ..... 
#2 ......Application function ..... 
#3 ......Application function .....                  
#4  0x00007f8b303c9494 in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-   gnu/libpthread.so.0                                                        
#5  0x00007f8b2f666aff in __libc_ifunc_impl_list () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6                                                         
#6  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 3 (Thread 0x7f8b30685700 (LWP 27025)):                            
#0  0x00007f8b303d27dd in __nanosleep_nocancel () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0                                                  
#1  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7f8b2eb31700 (LWP 27032)):                               
#0  0x00007f8b303d27dd in __nanosleep_nocancel () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0                                                   
#1  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()                                           

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f8b306c3700 (LWP 27022)):                              
 #0  0x00007f8b303d2f9f in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-                 gnu/libpthread.so.0
```

Here thread 2 and 3's stack trace showing __nanosleep_nocancel , where I expect stack trace be like thread 5.

any leads on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you can (and you aren't already doing so), try specifying -g as a compiler flag and -rdynamic as a flag to both your compiler and your linker.  It might be that your executable doesn't contain all the information necessary to construct a proper stack trace.

Comment: in good case I get the debugging information in the stacktrace of the thread like above thread 5 has right the debugging information while some threads stacktrace is vague due to which the thread which is dependent on thread displaying the stack trace vaguely crashing. This is stacktrace retrieved from the coredump of the process.

Comment: Thread 5's stack doesn't look all that useful to me -- for example, which function inside your thread-entry function was that thread running in, when the stack trace was generated?  I don't think you can tell.  It appears to give you symbols only from libpthread and libc, not from functions in your own code.

Comment: It was I did not copy here...